# Error sending archive to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, ipados

Yesterday, I updated to Xcode 13 via the App Store. I'm trying to send an archive of my app to App Store Connect through the usual way in the "Organizer" window, and once the archive is submitted, I get the warning message:

> App Store Connect Operation Warning
>
> Your version of iTMSTransporter will be updated in approximately 10 days.

I've never seen this before and have no idea what it means. The archive still shows in Testflight later and is useable, but I am not sure if it's safe to update the App Store version of my app with this archive build when it was uploaded with warnings.

**What is this warning, and how can I fix this?**

I also get this email about alternative icon errors after App Store Connect upload. I have alternative app icons enabled in the app and know for sure that I have 120x120 on iPhone, so I'm not sure why this is happening. But if this is nothing related to the upload warnings then kindly ignore the email:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:**
Looks like Apple has fixed this as my archives are uploading without that strange warning

Comment: Those are two unrelated questions. Could you please ask two separate questions?

Comment: You need to update the app icons for your app in your Assets.xcassets folder in your project.  You don't have every required image size for your AppIcon.  Welcome to iOS development.  :-)

Comment: @Waxhaw I just checked and I have app icon sizes for all of the ones it's complaining about. I even deleted and re-added them and still get both issues. Any tips of what else to do?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411974/failed-audit-on-first-questions-queue).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The message has nothing to do with the archive or the build. It's saying something about the tool you used to perform the upload from your computer to Apple. That tool is Xcode so there's nothing to worry about. There is always a little friction when a new major Xcode version is released but it gets ironed out at the server end eventually. You could file a bug with Apple if you want to be helpful.

Comment: Is it safe to upload this archive to the App Store? I have an app that's public, and I do not want to accidentally cause issues to any users.

Comment: From the first question, yes, totally. Your other question about icons is more problematic.

Comment: I got the exact same error and freaked but it's processing on TestFlight as expected.  Thanks Matt!  I was freaking as I have a deadline for QA tonight!

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky As I say, this sort of thing (in one way or another) always happens. My _guess_ is that at the server end they need to tell it, hey, it's ok, the Transporter tech built into Xcode 13 is valid. The issue will probably just go away in a couple of days.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky Well maybe you haven't been in this game as long as I have? As I say, my experience is that the iTunes / App Store Connect server has trouble of some sort _every_ time there's a new major iOS version. Apple just isn't very good at throwing all the switches in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Just a heads up for folks.  If you upgrade to MacOS 11.6 and then update your Xcode tools, this error will go away.  Happy Coding!

Comment: I've done both of them and was still getting this error. It looks like it was just an Apple thing and they fixed it their end now.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the Transporter User Guide 2.2 - Apple Support and tried again in Xcode to upload my app and it worked ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).