# iTMStransporter will be updated in approximately in 8 days

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

I don't know why I am getting this warning, How can I resolve it ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTgOE.jpg)

EDIT (SOLUTION),

I just received mail from Apple,

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "****". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
Best regards,
The App Store Team..

---

And I Added
NSCalendarsUsageDescription
NSAppleMusicUsageDescription

in Info.plist. and it got Resolved.

Comment: I think you will find more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277000/error-sending-archive-to-app-store-connect). It's a similiar question

Comment: Same warning here

Comment: I also get this error

Comment: I got same warning but it still uploded. I think it's only warning.

Comment: Same, looks like a warning. Any idea what we need to do here?

Comment: Anyone find solution of this error ?