# Xcode: Your version of iTMSTransporter will be updated in approximately 7 days

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app (v0.00) to AppStoreConnect yesterday evening and no problems. I fixed some bugs inside my app, expired the the build that I initially pushed up (v0.00) and when I pushed up a new build (v0.01) this morning I got the warning:

> Your version of iTMSTransporter will be updated in approximately 7
> days.

[image]

**What does that mean?** And why is it that between yesterday and today, probably a 6 hour difference, I'm now getting this error?

[image]

Looks like this is a brand new issue as other people are just running into this problem too. Read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/pstsny/app_store_connect_operation_warning_your_version/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690486), they just posted their issue a few hours before I posted mines

Comment: I've seen the same this morning - but the upload itself worked.

Comment: Yes, the upload worked but it’s still a warning. It’s just odd that I didn’t see it it a few hrs before the current upload

Comment: Hi @LanceSamaria there was any fix for this, i am also facing same?

Comment: @ParasGupta answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277095/4833705 . It's an Xcode issue, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LanceSamaria

Comment: Got it first time myself with Xcode 13.2, weird. Upload worked as usual, submitted my build for review just fine.