# App Store Connect Operation Error resource download failed : com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit/2.2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

When I tried to distribute the app binary to AppStore today, uploading failed and found the following errors.

> Distribution failed with errors:
>
> The following issues occurred while distributing your application.
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error resource  download failed :
> com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit/2.2.0
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error   unsatisfied requirement:
> com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error   unsatisfied requirement:
> com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error
> (&(package=com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error  unsatisfied requirement:
> com.apple.transporter.core

I've tried to resubmit but also failed again.
I am using Xcode12.4 on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6.
Distributing binary had been worked very well for few months, but today it is not working with the above issues.

**Edit: It looks like Apple has fixed this issue as my archives are uploading without any warnings though I didn't upgrade xCode and MacOS.**

Comment: How did you perform the export and upload? What software, what version?

Comment: Distributing binary had been worked very well for few months, but today it is not working with above issues. I am using Xcode12.4 on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Yes but now Xcode 13 is current so uploads with Xcode 12 might not work. Can you update to Big Sur and Xcode 13? If not... Try downloading the latest version of Transporter from the Mac App Store. Export for App Store Connect but save to a file and upload with Transporter. That _might_ work.

Comment: same issue with the latest version of Transporter from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Darn. Well, it's at the server end, it isn't your fault. I'm pretty sure it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277000/error-sending-archive-to-app-store-connect/ There's some sort of wrong setting at Apple's end. All you can really do is file a bug.

Comment: Same issue, I will try to update Xcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message has nothing to do with the archive or the build.
It's saying something about the tool you used to perform the upload from your computer to Apple. That tool is Xcode so there's nothing to worry about.
There is always a little friction when a new major Xcode version is released but it gets ironed out at the server end eventually

After several days, I could upload my archives/builds successfully without upgrading XCode and MacOS, it looks like Apple has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

a. Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
b. From Xcode's organizer, choose your archive and press "Distribute App"
c. Instead of "Upload", choose "Export" and proceed ahead as usual.
d. Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

another

upgrade xCode

another

Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration" are checked but none of the other proxy options are checked.
one had to uncheck "SOCKS Proxy" option to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install "Transporter" from de App Store, sign in with your apple ID and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just today.
restarted the router and it worked after that.
not sure what's the reason.

also go this warning on Sep 22

[image: iTMSTransporter warning on Sep 22]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and in my case it **seems related to network**. I just kept trying and after failing to distribute the app 3 times, the upload process finished successfully in the 4th retry.